# Using an iMac 27-inch as a display for a Mac Mini M1

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, mac-mini, displayport

I want to connect an iMac 27-inch Late 2012 and an iMac 27-inch Mid 2010 to two Mac Mini M1 and use them as displays, so I'd like to know what type of cable should I buy for each one of them.

The iMac Late 2012 has a Thunderbolt port and the Mid 2010 has a Mini DisplayPort.

Could someone please give a link to an online shop where I could buy these cables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible using Apple's "Target Display Mode" on the iMac, from an M1 Mac mini. Only Macs introduced in 2019 or earlier (i.e., Intel-based Macs) can connect to an older iMac's Target Display Mode (newer iMacs don't have Target Display Mode), according to the Apple support article https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592 which states:

> The iMac used as a display must have macOS High Sierra or earlier installed.
> The other Mac that you're connecting it to must have been introduced in 2019 or earlier and have macOS Catalina or earlier installed.

It is possible to modify some older iMac models, converting them from a computer to a monitor, by disconnecting their main circuit boards and replacing them with 3rd-party display driver boards. The boards currently sell for $200-300. You can search eBay, AliExpress, etc. for 5K universal HD driver boards. This is a very complicated procedure, it is not just buying a cable.

Comment: You're indeed correct, I missed that point. Thanks. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: That edit you made ‘n reverted was pretty funny!

Comment: Thank you! Extremely clear and helpful.